# 400 error due a SPRING conversion fail

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status-code-400

i'm trying to convert an id to an object using the SPRING `Converter` interface but i'm having i 400 bad request error when i post the form i have a code that looks like this 
this is the converter

```
@Component
public class LocationConverter implements Converter<Object, Location> {

@Autowired
LocationService locationService;

@Override
public Location convert(Object element) {

    Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String)element);
    Location l = locationService.getById(id);

    return l;
}
}
```

i'm using annotation based configuration so i'm registering it like this

```
@Override
 public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry){
     registry.addConverter(new CategoryConverter());
     registry.addConverter(new LocationConverter());
     registry.addConverter(new SupplierConverter());
 }
```

the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createOrUpdateArticle(@ModelAttribute Article article,String action,MultipartFile file) 
        throws IOException{

    if(action.equals("create")){
        if( !file.isEmpty() ) { 
            article.setImage(file.getBytes());
        }
        articleService.create(article);
    }

    if(action.equals("update")){
        articleService.update(article);
    }

    return "redirect:/article/";
}
```

and in the view

```
<f:form modelAttribute="article" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" 
                                        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/article/create">                                        
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="${action}"/>  
                                    <f:input type="hidden" path="id"/>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                        <label>CodeBarre</label>
                                        <f:input path="code" class="form-control"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                        <label>Description</label>
                                        <f:input path="description" class="form-control"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                        <label>Prix Grossier</label>
                                        <f:input path="price1" class="form-control"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                        <label>Prix Semi Grossier</label>
                                        <f:input path="price2" class="form-control"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Categorie</label>
                                            <f:select cssClass="form-control" path="category" items="${categories}" 
                                                      itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Location</label>
                                            <f:select cssClass="form-control" path="location" items="${locations}" 
                                                      itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Fournisseur</label>
                                            <f:select cssClass="form-control" path="suppliers" items="${suppliers}" 
                                                      multiple="true" itemValue="id" itemLabel="firstName"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Photo</label>
                                            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm-default pull-right">Ajouter</button>
                                </f:form>
```

the error message

```
Field error in object 'article' on field 'category': rejected value [3]; codes [typeMismatch.article.category,typeMismatch.category,typeMismatch.ma.stock.app.entities.Category,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [article.category,category]; arguments []; default message [category]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'ma.stock.app.entities.Category' for property 'category'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.persistence.ManyToOne ma.stock.app.entities.Category for value '3'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]
```

Field error in object 'article' on field 'location': rejected value [2]; codes [typeMismatch.article.location,typeMismatch.location,typeMismatch.ma.stock.app.entities.Location,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [article.location,location]; arguments []; default message [location]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'ma.stock.app.entities.Location' for property 'location'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.persistence.OneToOne ma.stock.app.entities.Location for value '2'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]
Field error in object 'article' on field 'suppliers': rejected value [4]; codes [typeMismatch.article.suppliers,typeMismatch.suppliers,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [article.suppliers,suppliers]; arguments []; default message [suppliers]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'suppliers'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.persistence.ManyToMany @javax.persistence.JoinTable ma.stock.app.entities.Supplier for value '4'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]

i don't know what i'm missing here, 
thanks in advance.

Comment: And where is the controller?

Comment: i updated the question and add the controller

Comment: Are you sure your form is sending the request as `POST` and not as `GET`?

Comment: yes, i'm send a POST request `method="post"`

Comment: Can you update your view then and put the whole form tag in your question? Usually a bad reqest results from missing call parameters. Maybe some form variable names are misspelled?

Comment: okay i edited the question, but don't thing that there's a missing or misspelled params cause spring would point that out, and i added the error message too